# What does “Intended for distribution with a new PC” mean on an OEM Windows 7 Home Premium CD?

Tags: windows-7, oem, windows-7-restore

I just bought a new gaming PC and it came with a Windows 7 Home Premium CD but it says on the top of the disk “Intended for distribution with a new PC.” Would I be able to use this disk on my other PC to make them Windows 7 from Windows 8?

Answer (score -1):

You can use it with a machine and once activated, it is bound to that machine only. You may reinstall or clean install using the key in that machine as many times you like, but not to a new machine.

ie, once the the key is activated with the new machine, its illegal to use it on your old Windows 8 machine.

OEM: Original Equipment Manufacturer, can be defined as entity or person who makes or assembles the PC....

For installing on a different PC, you will need the retail version, not OEM one.

Comment: Have you actually read the license, and can you comment on how this interplays with the "first sale doctrine" ?  (I've actually read some Windows Licenses - and there is nothing clear-cut about the fineprint)  This issue is a whole lot more complext then most people think - and indeed there does not seem to be an aweful lot of case law on it.

Comment: Yes, but not the fine print/hard copy. About "first sale doctrine", if I'm not mistaken by the definition, I think it deals with the right of end user/reseller which is why I think they have the retail version. From my own experience with the OEM/system builder versions, I have faced trouble while activating Windows after once the hardware has some significant change (like change in motherboard). That's where my comments are based on. Does it create any issue?

Comment: From a practical view, once the OS is actually installed it gets bound to a machine based on its fingerprint - but this does not stop the initial install on a different machine.  The first sale doctrine is about your rights as a purchaser - for example, a book publisher can't stop you reselling a book, and - at least in my country - the "not for resale" labels on various items is not binding on the final user.  Of-course, a license is a much greyer area.

Answer (score -2):

Yes and no.

From a technical point of view you can install Windows 7 Home Premium on your old PC - but probably not upgrade/downgrade your existing installation.

From a legal point of view it depends on the license terms in the fineprint, and you would need to speak to Microsoft (or maybe your retailer) to find out if you are truely legal.   [ It also may depend on consumer laws in your country ]